# Passing a function as an argument Tones.js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple function which creates faders. So far i have got the fader to appear and have no errors however the fader simply doesn't work. Here is my Function:

```
function createSlider(name, max, min, value, inputFunction, elementId) 
{
  var name = document.createElement("input");
  name.setAttribute("type", "range");
  name.setAttribute("max", max);
  name.setAttribute("min", min);
  name.setAttribute("value", value);
  name.setAttribute("input", inputFunction);

  document.getElementById(elementId).appendChild(name);
}
```

I then call the function

```
createSlider("myTestSlider", "100", "-100", "0", panFader, "holder1");
```

Here is the 'panFader()' function

```
function panFader() {
     var myPanFAderValue = this.value/100;
     pan.pan.value = myPanFaderValue; 
}
```

I'm quite new to javascript so I am not so sure on the syntax of passings functions as arguments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this `name.setAttribute("input", inputFunction);` basically do?

Comment: Tells the slider to 'look' at the panFader() function.

Comment: I don't understand what `look` you are talking about. Also `.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE, VALUE)` only accept `string` for value not function or anything else.

Comment: ok, so I can't put a function there? thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can't, to be make us able to help you any further you should elaborate your idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have realised my mistake, instead of a setAttritube i need to use '.addEventListener("input", panFader);' Sorry to waste your time.